# How to parse dynamic headers and empty lines?

Tags: csv, meteor, papaparse

How do you parse csv files that have different header names?
I was trying to do it somewhat like this in meteor method:

```
parseUpload(data){
check(...)
for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  let item = data[i]
  let thing = {
    name: item.name || item.itemname || item.something,
    category: item.category
  }
  items.insert(thing);
}
```

but it was always taking the first param (item.name) and as it was empty, the method couldn't be executed. How do i do OR statement to bind name to doc.namesArray so uploaded file can use aliases for column names?

also, i have noticed that when you make spreadsheet not starting from 1A, it creates empty lines/rows in csv document. papaparse still expects first column to be "name" and everything stops working again (untill i recreate csv file so it starts with actual values).

Answer (score 0):

If you try to paste this code into the console window in your browser:

```
item={name:' ',itemname:"itemname",something:"something"}
item.name || item.itemname || item.something
```

You'll get this:

```
" "
```

Similarly with this:

```
item={name:'',itemname:"itemname",something:"something"}
item.name || item.itemname || item.something
```

You get

```
"itemname"
```

So if item.name is an empty string, or missing, then you get `item.itemname` returned

So the code is ok, your data must not be as you expect. Try putting a console.log(item) in and see what you get, or set a breakpoint and inspect it.

Comment: yeah but when i upload file that has only one of those expected headers, it responses with "sanitized and reported to the client as: name is required [400].